# Which test is most appropriate?

Tags: anova, t-test

My experiment had 3 tubs, each containing the same substrate. I  grew maggots in the substrate of each tub.

Once mature, 3 samples of these maggots were harvested from each tub giving me 9 subjects.

The rest of the maggots were left in the tub and  developed into flies which laid eggs. these eggs then hatched into maggots and, once mature, another 3 samples were taken from each tub, giving 9 more subjects.

All 18 of these subjects then had their nutritional values analysed, giving results on all minerals, amino-acids and fatty-acids.

So I have a dataset of 18 subjects. 9 of the samples are replicates of treatment 1 (1st generation) and 9 are replicates from treatment 2(2nd generation). There are then 3 groups, with each containing 3 cross treatment replicates.

Using the mineral calcium (Ca) as an example, my null hypothesis is:

The generation (1st or 2nd) of a larval sample makes no difference to the Ca content of that sample.

What test do I use to test this hypothesis?

My initial thought was a dependent t-test as I am comparing the means of 1st gen to 2nd gen. However, this doesn't incorporate the 3 replicate tubs. As far as a t-test knows each pair of samples either came from their own tubs, or one big one. I have been trying to incorporate these 3 replicate groups within the 9  pre and post replicates for so long that I cannot see the wood for the trees anymore.

Which test is most appropriate?

Comment: +1.  This is a very nice example of how to ask a good question: it clearly describes your experiment and your problem from your perspective, briefly explains how you are thinking, and winds up with single direct statistical question.